# Entity Framework Core 2.1 - Error while saving one to many related records

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have configured the one to many relationship as explained below. There is no actual foreign key set in the SQL tables though.

```
//Parent Entity
public partial class Summary
{
    public Summary()
    {
        DetailRecords = new HashSet<Details>();
    }
    public Guid DocUnid { get; set; }
    //Some other columns
    public ICollection<Details> DetailRecords { get; set; }
}

//Child Entity
public partial class Details
{
    public Guid DocUnid { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentRecordUnid { get; set; }
    //Some other columns
    public Summary SummaryRecord { get; set; }
}

//Code from DbContext class
modelBuilder.Entity<Details>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.DocUnid);
    entity.ToTable("Details", "App");

    entity.Property(e => e.DocUnid)
        .HasColumnName("DocUNID")
        .HasDefaultValueSql("(newid())");

    entity.Property(e => e.ParentRecordUnid).HasColumnName("ParentRecordUNID");

    entity.HasOne(x => x.SummaryRecord)
    .WithMany(y => y.DetailRecords)
    .HasForeignKey(z => z.ParentRecordUnid);
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Summary>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.DocUnid);

    entity.ToTable("Summary", "App");

    entity.Property(e => e.DocUnid)
        .HasColumnName("DocUNID")
        .HasDefaultValueSql("(newid())");
    //Tried below code also
    //entity.HasMany(x => x.DetailRecords)
    //.WithOne(y => y.SummaryRecord)
    //.HasForeignKey(z => z.ParentRecordUnid);
});


//Code to save records
public async void Save(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    var summary = Mapper.Map<Summary>(viewModel);
    foreach (Details row in summary.DetailRecords)
    {
        //Setting some other column values here
    }
    await _unitOfWork.Summaries.AddAsync(summary);
    await _unitOfWork.CompleteAsync(default(CancellationToken));
}
```

It says "Failed executing DbCommand", followed by "System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation. The connection is closed".

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I am just wondering if this kind of operation is currently supported in EF Core 2.1.

**UPDATE:**

I removed the navigation properties to make sure the error is not related to one to many relation. I am still getting the following error.

> App>fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction[20205]
>   App>      An error occurred using a transaction.
>   App>System.InvalidOperationException: This SqlTransaction has
>   completed; it is no longer usable. App>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.ZombieCheck() App>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Commit() App>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTransaction.Commit()

Comment: Add the code that calls the `Save` method. `_unitOfWork` may be getting disposed before finishing the operation

Comment: It looks like that is the issue. I will post the relevant code soon.